# How to close and stop form activity .

Tags: c#, winforms

I started a game project in c# and i ran in to a problem . 
In the game there is a map form that has buttons , when you click on a button a new form is opend- field.
My problem is that i dont know how to close the form(field) activity after i finish with it.
this.close() doesnt to the job and the form continue to work even if i cant see it.

```
private void Charmove_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          .
          .
          Messagebox.show("you won the stage well done");
          this.close();//problem
           g.show;
    }
```

Comment: how do you know that the form is still working

Comment: Your question is not clear. In what way does "the form continue to work if you cant see it?"

Comment: No the problem form what you've posted is g.Show. Could do with the code that shows this new form, but the code you've posted is a symptom of an earlier error.

Comment: thanks guys .. i wasnt really clear but i managed to solve the problem .

Comment: Consider adding the answer your self and accept it - that way everybody knows your problem was solved. This is perfectly OK on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Does your game use a `Timer`? If so, then stop it before closing the form.

```
private void Charmove_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    timer1.Stop();
    Messagebox.Show("You've won the stage. Well done!");
    this.Close();
    g.Show();
}
```